# Of web service implementation

Tags: python, web-services

I am trying to implement a small, very flexible REST web service. I've done it in the past, but I didn't like the approach and I still don't like. How can one parse the query variables in a more elegant way ? Doing things like:

`if query_variable in uri: do_things_based_on_query_variable`

look fairly ugly to me, especially when all of those query variables map back to a database.

Can someone give an example of how an Web Service is implemented ? I am interested mostly in Python Web Services and how they're handled in the controller implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Routes](http://routes.groovie.org/)?